# Are pointers just the same as global variables?

Tags: variables, pointers

They seem to have more or less the same purpose.
they told me that pointers are just memory addresses of data locations so that instead of passing large objects and data, you just pass a number.
but i still can't see difference.

please, explain.

Comment: They are entirely separate concepts. One is a concept of memory, and the other is a concept of scope.

Comment: @4castle You should convert that into an answer and elaborate on it - I suspect that the OP might not understand the difference between the two.

Comment: Here is a very good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892198/whats-the-difference-between-pointers-and-global-variables-in-c

Answer (score 2):

No, they aren't the same since you need access to the pointer to access what it points to.

Unless you make the pointer global, you can't access what it points to from everywhere.

Comment: Even then, the data needs to also be global so that the pointer doesn't point to something that's been garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

A **pointer** is a type of variable that stores a memory address. They can have scope just as any other variable. A **global** variable is a variable with global scope, meaning it can be accessed from anywhere.

Just because a pointer is global, it doesn't mean the data in memory is global. If the data in memory is garbage collected from going out of scope (e.g. from an `if` statement ending or a `function` ending), the pointer will now point to re-purposed memory, and the value at that memory address will be unpredictable.

If anything, pointers are generally used as a way to share local variables *without* creating a global variable. Instead, you only pass the pointer to functions you *want* to share the value with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're talking about c++. Pointers are not global unless you assign it to a variable that is global. Here is an example in c and should be the same in c++:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 5; //Global variable 
int* x_pointer = &x; //global pointer that holds the address of x

int main() {
    int y = 43; //Local variable
    int* y_pointer = &y; //local pointer that holds the address of y
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!